# Multivariable partial differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $f(r,\theta)=r^5\cos \theta$,$x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin \theta$
>
> Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ in therms of $r$ and $\theta$

I know that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\cdot \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$$

so I have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=5r^4\cos \theta$

$x=r\cos \theta \Rightarrow r=\frac{x}{cos\theta}$

so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$

Or because $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

It is $r=\frac{x}{\cos \theta}=\frac{x}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{r}=cos\theta$
?

Comment: A simple way (in this case) to find $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and the rest is to compute the Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial(r,\theta)}{\partial(x,y)}$ and invert it. That’s essentially what you’ll end up doing when you use the method in M. Strochyk’s answer.

Comment: @amd can you please refer me to more info about this method?

Comment: The Jacobian ${\partial(x,y)\over\partial(r,\theta)}$ (note the typo in my previous comment) is just the array of partial derivatives: $\pmatrix{x_r&x_{\theta}\\ y_r&y_{\theta}}$. This is also the differential $d\phi$, where $\phi$ is the polar-to-cartesian mapping. The inverse function theorem tells us that, except at the origin, $d(\phi^{-1})=(d\phi)^{-1}$, so the inverse of the above matrix is equal to $\pmatrix{r_x&r_y\\ \theta_x&\theta_y}$. This is the multidimensional equivalent of taking the reciprocal of $df/dx$ to find the derivative of $f^{-1}$ for $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} 
\end{cases}
$$
and solve this system w.r.t. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
f &= r^5 \cos \theta = r^4 \cdot r \cos \theta = x \cdot \left ( x^2 + y^2\right)^2 \implies \\
f_x &= \left ( x^2 + y^2\right)^2 + x \cdot 2(x^2 + y^2) \cdot 2x = \left ( x^2 + y^2\right) \left( x^2 + y^2 + 4x^2\right) = \\
&= \left ( x^2 + y^2\right) \left ( 5x^2 + y^2\right) = r^4 \left ( 5 \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta\right) \\
f_y &= 4x y \left ( x^2 + y^2\right) = 4r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta \cdot r^2 = 4r^4 \cos \theta \sin \theta
\end{align}
You can simplify even more, if you want, using trig identities.